# Code works in debug and running from visual studio however release mode gives error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

There are many questions on debug and release however my case is different.
Below is my code

```
private void frmMDIStpDataView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] tempCommandLine = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    if (tempCommandLine.Count() > 1 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tempCommandLine[1]))
        ModFormManager.strTmpPath = tempCommandLine[1];
    m_FormManager = ModFormManager.FormManager;//Line where i am getting object reference error
        //some other code
};
```

`ModFormManager` is a static class all its members are static.`FormManager` is a object of Non static class. This error wont come in Debug more and Release mode if i run from Visual studio 2013. If i double click on exe which is build in release more i get error. I am getting innerexception as **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"**

Comment: What exception do you get exactly? You know that the first entry in GetCommandLineArgs is the filename of the executable and the rest are the additional parameters entered on command line.

Comment: `FormManager` of `ModFormManager` is not set to an instance of an object. Where are you calling the constructor of `ModFormManager`? Are you sure `FormManager` is initialized? Is it getting initialized via something that works in your local but not in release? Some configuration error?

Comment: if the Exception is in the property ModFormManager.FormManager, you should publish the code of the property. Code you published is irrelevant regarding your error.

Comment: @FabienBondi i had kept messagebox in the constructor of FormManager however code flow doesn't go there it error outs before that.

Comment: This is yet another case where a programmer finds out that writing an event handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event is *not* optional.  If you don't then you just have no idea why code fails without a debugger attached.  And it is never simple when it is a field initializer of the Form class that causes the exception.  Calling Debugger.Launch() is the Q&D way.

Answer (score 0):

Debug modes often initialize heap data allocations. The program might be dependent on this behavior. Look for variables and buffers that are not getting initialized.Like in this case  ModFormManager wasn't initialized. Create the object of  ModFormManager and then use it.